# Motion planning from moveIt to robot studio..execution time problem

Tags: ros, moveit, motionplanning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Working on IRB2400 robot and ROS_Industrial abb-indigo package

I have successfully planned the motion in moveit and simulate it on robot studio but the motion in robot studio is very slow and taking too much time , because of this problem the robot at the Robot Studio side is not ablle to complete the planned trajectory ..i am getting the following error on linux side.. PLease help me, how to takle this problem:
Thanks!

```
[ERROR] [1487880741.130427078]: Controller is taking too long to execute trajectory (the expected upper bound for the trajectory execution was 5.791247 seconds). Stopping trajectory.
[ INFO] [1487880741.130543359]: MoveitSimpleControllerManager: Cancelling execution for 
[ INFO] [1487880741.130783310]: Execution completed: TIMED_OUT
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255459/motion-planning-from-moveit-to-robot-studio..execution-time-problem/) by [Muneeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/29399/muneeb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-02-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're running into the MoveIt Trajectory Execution Manager stepping in and aborting the trajectory execution because of a violation of the timing constraints.

See #q196586 for a related question and answer.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Muneeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/29399/muneeb/) on 2017-02-24**:
I did changes as mentioned in #q196586 but that didn't work for me. Then i increased the value of "allowed_goal_duration_margin" from 0.5 to 3  in "trajectory_execution.launch.xml" : after that it works fine for me